# How to create a label whose value is only known after a RUN command

Tags: docker

When building a Docker image, the value of a label can only be known after executing a `RUN` command.

I can write the contents of the *label* in a file o set an environment variable or whatever.
But how can I set a label with this value?

I've seen that I can only set this value:

- to a fixed value in the Dockerfile.  I can use environment variables.
- to a variable value in the command line when building (`docker build  --label name=value -t myimage:latest .`)

Comment: You cannot set a `LABEL` with the output of a `RUN` command, what you can do (as you mentioned) is to provide it through `ARG`, environment variables or directly setting it at build time. If you put your Dockerfile and the desired value in the `LABEL`, maybe I could help you with some insight about what could you do.

Comment: A possible solution is to invoke docker build twice, the 1st invocation is to get the value of the label, and the 2nd is to build the final image with the correct label.  This isn't optimal, but it must work.